# Export 3D object, Mathematica

Tags: export, wolfram-mathematica, .obj

I've been researching this, but I cannot find a simple *example* for how to do this.  I would like to export a 3D object as an .obj into a specified folder.

Comment: The documentation (eg http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/OBJ.html) provides what looks like a simple example to me.  What exactly are you stuck on ?

Comment: You can use `SetDirectory[]` to specify current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
Export["Your file name.obj", "Your 3D object"]
```

You can find examples here: 
http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/OBJ.html